# РЕШЕНО - Mysql. Warning: mysql.service changed on disk

Tags: mysql, debian

Warning: mysql.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.

ОС Debian 9

Ошибка возникает после попытки перезагрузить mysql
service mysql restart

Запускаю 'systemctl daemon-reload' - не помогает.

Ошибка возникла после удаления всех логов из-за переполнения системного диска.

Началось все с того что после reboot удалялся mysqld.sock
создавал файл вручную, владельцем делал mysqld - не помогло.

Переустановил Mysql - не помогло. (apt-get install mysql-server)

при команде
service mysql reload - пишет [OK]

Файл my.cnf - сейчас

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

После перезагрузки системы не могу зайти в mysql выдает ошибку

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Что делать чтобы исправить ошибку? 3 дня гуглю ничего из предложенного им не помогает?

**РЕШЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ:**

удалил mysql-server полностью!
по инструкции:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely

установил с репозитория по инструкции:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install

Установил mysql 8
Если так же захотите установить ее, при задании пароля выдаст выбор шифрования, оставьте такое же как и в mysql 5.x, т.к. иначе будут проблемы со входом в phpmyadmin как минимум.

Comment: «Запускаю 'systemctl daemon-reload' - не помогает.» — на самом деле помогает

Comment: Во всяком случае проблему не решает. т.к. после запуска 'systemctl daemon-reload'  та же ошибка выводилась.